# java.lang.RuntimeException error occured while executing doInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am beginner in android, and for a project for a uny course we have to develop 5 simple apps and then "combine" them in one.So you start each app from a single Activity/ListView. **All the apps are running ok individually but when running one app from the listview i get the following**
**AsyncTask #1
 an error occured while executing doinBackground();**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    reportarray= new ArrayList<String>();


    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.yr.no/sted/Sverige/Kronoberg/V%E4xj%F6/forecast.xml");
        AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
    } catch (IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter= new Adapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);



}
```

It seems that is a thread issue , here is some more code i use

```
private class WeatherRetriever extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, WeatherReport> {
    protected WeatherReport doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            return WeatherHandler.getWeatherReport(urls[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(WeatherReport result) {
        report = result;




        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {



                  reportarray.add(report.toString());;

                  for (WeatherForecast forecast : report) {
                        reportarray.add(forecast.toString());

                    }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
            });
        PrintReportToConsole();


    }
}
```

}

LOGCAT OUTPUT

```
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.example.ass1.VaxjoWeather$WeatherRetriever.doInBackground(VaxjoWeather.java:133)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.example.ass1.VaxjoWeather$WeatherRetriever.doInBackground(VaxjoWeather.java:1)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     ... 4 more
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.example.ass1.WeatherHandler.getWeatherReport(WeatherHandler.java:54)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.example.ass1.VaxjoWeather$WeatherRetriever.doInBackground(VaxjoWeather.java:131)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     ... 7 more
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
09-10 14:51:36.347: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
```

Comment: Add logs in the question

Comment: Can you post logcat output here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you don't have the appropriate permissions. Add this line to your `manifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thank you codeMagic , i dont have enouph reputation to vote up , sorry:)